# Proper implementation of functions with noexcept C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

Are those functions correctly implementing `noexcept` / `throw()`

### Fisrst function

```
void do_something(const std::string s) noexcept{
    // do something with no exception
}

do_something("Hello");
```

`"Hello" literal` will create new `std::string` object and it might throw an exception.

Is this exception will be thrown outside of the function or inside?

### Second function:

```
size_t do_something(const char *s) noexcept{
    return strlen(s);
}

do_something(nullptr);
```

`strlen` is chosen because it is legacy `C` function and it will crash, because `s` is `nullprt`.

However this crash is nothing to do with exceptions. Is the assumption correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In:

```
void do_something(const std::string s) noexcept
```

The argument `s` is constructed by the caller. That is, if constructing `std::string` throws an exception, that exception is thrown before `do_something` is called.

---

> `strlen` is chosen because it is legacy C function and it will crash, because `s` is `nullptr`.

Technically, accessing memory through invalid pointers results in undefined behaviour. No C++ exceptions are thrown in such cases and the compiler/run-time are not required to detect that.

Unlike Java which throws `NullPointerException`. Those Java checks for null pointers may be cheap, but they are not free.

On Linux/Unix you are most likely to get `SIGSEGV` signal whose default behavior is to terminate the process. You could install your own signal handler and make it throw a C++ exception, but that would result in even more undefined behaviour.

So, it is best if it crashed as early and loudly as possible so that the code is fixed.

> However this crash is nothing to do with exceptions. Is the assumption correct?

Correct, a crash is not an exception. A crash can be caused by an exception though.

Comment: can you elaborate about second part? I specifically asked for `strlen`, because it is legacy `C` function and there are no exceptions in `C`.

Comment: @Nick elaborated for you.

Comment: one unrelated Java question - do you happen to know who check and throw NullPointerException ? Additional code generated by the compiler or "standard library" do actual checking and throw?